# Where can I find Airflow route information of stable version API(v1.0.0) in Github?

Tags: flask, airflow, openapi

Where can I find Airflow route information of stable version API(v1.0.0) on Github?

I figured out all the endpoint exist as python scripts in `/airflow/api_connexion/endpoints`

But I don't know how each of file actually connected to endpoint in url

eg. `dag_endpoint.py` -> DOMAIN/api/v1/dags

I need which source code(file) defines route information of all the endpoints.

---

cf) I could only find [those of the experimental version](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py) on GitHub

(Maybe cuz i'm not familliar with flask, idk)

Comment: please clarify your question. What information do you need? Source code? Documentation? Why you try to find it on github?

Comment: @Mol0ko I specified question. of course i found files on github and there was nothing i could figure out with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow 2.0.0 rest API documentation can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/stable-rest-api-ref.html).

The python files are not "connected" you need the `dag_id` within your DAG code.

So if you have `dag_endpoint.py` that contains:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
)
```

The path is:

```
api/v1/dags/{dag_id}
```

for the `tutorial` DAG it's:

```
api/v1/dags/tutorial
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to use it. I wonder what is the source code which defines route information (eg. file where @app.route('/') is defined). the experimental version has its own, like I linked above

Comment: I found it!! this one. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/extensions/init_views.py
thx for help! @Elad